# Display different images in multiple MATLAB GUI windows

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I am creating a program in matlab that at some points will have two windows open. Both windows try to display a different image via:

```
matlabImage = imread('C:...SetupA.jpg');
imshow(matlabImage);
axis off
axis image
```

But what ends up happening is sometimes the image from the second GUI window to open will override the image in the first GUI window until it is closed, and the second GUI window displays nothing. I have made sure there are no reused image variable names. What can I do to prevent this?

Edit: so here are the two GUI windows that interfere with each other

```
function varargout = ClampRef(varargin)
%Function that displays an image with multiple reference points highlighted
%This needs to have an option to stay open while the program continues
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @ClampRef_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @ClampRef_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end

function ClampRef_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
matlabImage5 = imread('C:...reference.jpg');
imshow(matlabImage5)
axis off
axis image
handles.output = hObject;

guidata(hObject, handles);
set(handles.pushbutton2,'enable','off')



function varargout = ClampRef_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

uiwait();
global valueout;
varargout{1} = valueout;

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
%This is a continue button, which enables the close button but continues the    
%program
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global valueout;
valueout = 'Finished';
set(handles.pushbutton2,'enable','on')
set(handles.pushbutton1,'enable','off')
uiresume();




% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2. This is the close button
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
closereq();
```

and the second one:

```
function varargout = OHMgui1(varargin)
%Calculator like gui to take in the electrical test value while showing an
%image that shows where the probe must be placed for the test


gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @OHMgui1_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @OHMgui1_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end

function OHMgui1_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
matlabImage6 = imread('C:...pos1.jpg');
axis image;

imshow(matlabImage6);

handles.output = hObject;


guidata(hObject, handles);



% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = OHMgui1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
uiwait();
% Get default command line output from handles structure
global valueout;
varargout{1} = valueout;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value, '1');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'2');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'3');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton4.
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'4');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton5.
function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'5');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton6.
function pushbutton6_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton6 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'6');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton7.
function pushbutton7_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton7 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'7');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton8.
function pushbutton8_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton8 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'8');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton9.
function pushbutton9_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton9 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'9');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton10.
function pushbutton10_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton10 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value,'0');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton11.
function pushbutton11_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton11 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = strcat(value, '.');
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton12.
function pushbutton12_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton12 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
value = '';
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
guidata(hObject, handles);


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton13.
function pushbutton13_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton13 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
global valueout;
valueout = value;
value = '';
set(handles.answer_staticText,'String',value);
if strcmp(valueout, '')==1

  f = errordlg('Please enter a value','Null Value Error');  
elseif length(find(valueout=='.'))>1
  f = errordlg('Value has more than 1 decimal','Decimal Value Error');
else
    closereq(); 
end


function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global value;
disp (value);
while 1==1
    set(hObject,'String', value)
end


% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

I tried using figure, imshow() but it still did not resolve the issue

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer this question without a [mcve]. Broadly, based on this and your last question, I'd advise you look at implementing some [OOP](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/object-oriented-programming.html) into the structure of your code, this will help you better control your interfaces and their properties.

Comment: Use new [`figure`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html)s

Comment: @Wolfie sorry, I added the code of the two interfering GUIs